# What does html.escape serve for?

Tags: python, html, flask

I am looking at his Flask app

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def mainpage():

    name = default_name
    if request.method == 'POST':
        name = html.escape(request.form['name'], quote=True)
```

And unittest class

```
class TestCase(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_html_escaping(self):
    page = self.app.post("/", data=dict(name='"><b>TEST</b><!--'))
    assert '<b>' not in str(page.data)
```

I do not undestand why we need html.escape here.I have looked at Python docs,it says that its purpose

```
Convert the characters &, < and > in string s to HTML-safe sequences
```

Which HTML sequences are safe,which are not safe?

Comment: Because , the form can be anything , so if you do no Convert it in the case of danger input will crash your machine or inject your DB ..